# Why does my mesh get all smoothed out when I join it to another mesh?

Tags: modeling

I created a table top in Blender and then I made four legs for it. I got the smoothing right on the legs and everything looked fine. But when I join the two together, it looks like Blender just smoothed out all the faces and it looks a mess. I know I can go back and fix these problems manually but obviously I'm not doing some thing wrong. Here are the two meshes before joining them:[image]

Comment: This is the result

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on one model and not the other? If so they will be transferred when you join the parts so it's best to apply the modifiers before joining objects unless both have identical modifiers, both with the same settings. I'm thinking of Subdivision and Bevel modifiers in particular.

Comment: No, i made sure I collapsed the modifiers several times. I have fixed my model manually but I shouldn't have to. It was like Blender just put on the max smooting when I attached the legs to the top!

Comment: What do you mean by collapsing the modifiers several times? Usually in those structures expanding and collapsing means you either reveal or hide sublevels, which would be the options of the modifiers in this case. This is not applying the modifier, applying a modifier you can only do once, then it's gone - not several times.

Comment: I meant to say "applied."

Comment: And you did this by hilighting the modifier on the panel and using Ctrl-A or clicking Apply on the dropdown beside the camera icon on each modifier so that it vanished from the modifier panel? - If it was still there even if minimised, you didn't apply it!

Comment: @bobcooksey Well, if everything was done correctly and still doesn't work, then we cannot do anymore except asking you to upload your file here and edit it into your question for further investigation: https://blend-exchange.com But one last question: is _Auto Smooth_ enabled under _Object Data Properties > Normals_?